# JavaScript Form Validation - What is wrong with this code?

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, web

I am simply adding text into the input field for practice. It seems that when I press submit, the text appears in the input field for a short second then disappears. Could someone please tell me why this is happening? How can I get the messages to stay?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Title</title>
<script src="EventUtil.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <input type="text" name="poop1"> <br>
        <input type="text" name="poop1"> <br>
        <input type="text" name="poop1"> <br>
        <input type="text" name="poop1"> <br>
        <input type="submit" value="submit" id="btn">
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        EventUtil.addHandler(window,"load", function() {
            var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
            EventUtil.addHandler(btn,"click",function(){
                var i;
                for (i=0; i<document.forms[0].elements.length-1; i++){
                    if (document.forms[0].elements[i].value == ""){
                        document.forms[0].elements[i].value = "fill this poop in";
                    }
                }
            })
        })
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you're submitting the form, which reloads the current page. That's why you see the values for only a moment.

To fix it, use a `<button type="button">` instead of an `<input type="submit">`.

Comment: Wells said. Also a submit button could be used as long as return false the handler.

Comment: @Verhaeren: I may be wrong, but I think that only works if the handler is on the `form` element. *EDIT:* Yep, just tested it. Also if `addEventListener()` is being used, `return false` doesn't work. He would need to use `e.preventDefault()`.

Comment: That's a tricky matter. see here: http://jsfiddle.net/kxebt756/

Comment: @Verhaeren: Interesting. Different behavior between the two.

Answer (score 0):

You should put the listener on the form's submit handler, not the submit button, as the form can be submitted without clicking the button. Either add an ID to the form, or use the document's [*forms* collection](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/single-page.html#dom-document-forms):

```
var form = document.forms[0];
```

or

```
var form = document.getElementById('formID');
```

As noted in other answers, the form is submitting so the page refreshes. To cancel submit, return false from the listener.

Within the listener, *this* should reference the form:

```
EventUtil.addHandler(form, 'submit', function(){
    var control, controls = this.elements;

    for (var i=0, iLen=controls.length; i<iLen; i++) {
      control = controls[i];

      if (control.type == 'input' && control.type == 'text' && control.value == '') {
        control.value = 'fill this shit in';
        return false;
      }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use the required attribute on the form elements